# Python - Looping through functions is throwing errors in bg, until maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python

So I think I am just fundamentally doing something wrong, but here is a basic example of what I am doing

```
some variables here
some code here to run once

def runfirst():
    do some stuff
    runsecond()
def runsecond():
    do some different stuff
    runthird():
def runthird():
    do some more stuff
    runfirst():
runfirst()
```

So it basically pulls some info I need at beginning, and then runs through 3 different variables.  What I am doing is pulling info from db, then watching some counts on the db, and if any of those counts goes over a certain number over a time period, it sends email.  This is for monitoring purposes, and I need it to run all the time.  The problem I get is, all the time it is running, in the background it is throwing errors like "File "asdf.py", line blah, in firstrun"

I think it is complaining because it sees that I am looping through functions, but for what I need this to do, it works perfectly, except for the errors, and eventually killing my script due to maximum recursion depth exceeded.  Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have infinite recursion here. Because you call `runfirst` from `runthird`, it keeps going deeper and deeper and none of the functions ever return. You might want to consider putting the functions in a `while True` loop instead of calling them from each other.

```
def runfirst():
    do some stuff
def runsecond():
    do some different stuff
def runthird():
    do some more stuff

while True:
    runfirst()
    runsecond()
    runthird()
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Didn't know easiest(correct) way to just iterate through them.  Thanks, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You're not looping.

You're calling a function that calls another function that calls a third function that calls the first function which calls the second function which calls the third function which again calls the first function...and so on until your stack overflows.